# Criar sinônimo para tag «apple-push-notification»

Tags: debate, suporte, tag-específica, tags-sinônimas

Encontrei ambas tags: [apple-push-notification](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notification) e [apns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apns), creio que APNS seja abreviatura de **A**pple **P**ush **N**otification **S**ervice, como não tenho score em nenhuma das tags não posso sugerir como sinônimo.

No entanto gostaria de pedir a comunidade e/ou quem puder, sugerir [apns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apns) como sendo sinônimo de [apple-push-notification](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notification), já que ambas são usadas com o mesmo proposito.

No caso creio que [apple-push-notification](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notification) seria a tag principal, claro que para quem tiver experiencia com esta tecnologia e preferir [apns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apns) também é bem vindo a sugerir.

Comment: Ué, ainda não foi criado?

Comment: Por mais que eu goste de abreviaturas, prefiro a descrição completa para ser a principal. Assim, independente do contexto em que aparecer, consegue-se entender o sentido da tag rapidamente, principalmente pra pessoas que não estão familiarizadas com ela.

Comment: Google: *"Você quis dizer **A**ccess **P**oint **N**ame**s**?"*

Comment: @EMBarbosa isso é opcional, a minha sugestão é que apns seja o sinônimo apenas, ou seja quando o cara digita apns o sistema converte para apple-push-notification... O "service" acho que é redundante no nome da tag

Comment: Você já sugeriu o sinônimo na tag wiki? Porque eu não tenho pontos suficientes para sugerir...

Comment: @EMBarbosa justamente por isso abri a questão do Meta, como eu disse no começo da pergunta *"como não tenho score em nenhuma das tags não posso sugerir como sinônimo."*, moderadores podem criar sem precisar de pontos na tag, ou usuários com pontos, minha esperança é que um dos 2 tipos de pessoa leiam esta postagem e sugiram ou criem diretamente o sinônimo.

Comment: Acho que vai ter que ser moderadores. A lista de usuários principais dessas tags é muito pequena...

Comment: @EMBarbosa sim, o que vier primeiro.